# Android: open file through other applications

Tags: android, android-activity

How to get data from the file which is opened from other applications? For example, I open a file from default file manager and `open with` my application, and then how to get the data from the file that I open?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am guessing that your app has an activity with an `ACTION_VIEW` `<intent-filter>`.

If so, you can call `getData()` on the `Intent` that was used to start your activity to get the `Uri` pointing to the content that the user wishes to view. You can call `getContentResolver()` on your `Activity` or other `Context` to get a `ContentResolver` object. Call `openInputStream()` on the `ContentResolver` to get an `InputStream` on the content. Ideally, do that work on a background thread.

[This sample app](https://gitlab.com/commonsguy/cw-jetpack-java/tree/v0.4/Diceware) and [this sample app](https://gitlab.com/commonsguy/cw-jetpack-java/tree/v0.4/ContentEditor) (both from [this book](https://commonsware.com/Jetpack) show how to use a `ContentResolver` to get the `InputStream` for the content identified by a `Uri`. In my case, I am using `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT` rather than responding to `ACTION_VIEW`, but the rest is the same.

Note that your viewing activity has two sources of `Intent` objects:

- When the activity is started initially, and so an instance is created, the `Intent` used for that is available via `getIntent()`
- If the user opens another piece of content, and an existing instance of your activity is reused, that activity will be called with `onNewIntent()`, and you are passed the `Intent` that was used for this particular request